# How did he find the wormhole breach?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

I've just watched *The Flash S2* episode 3 where Snart confronted with his fanatic father; Jay stabilised the *breach* at S.T.A.R. Labs, Cisco saved Snart's sis & Iris getting back her mom.

> But the major moment of the episode was the coming of Harrison Wells. Well he is not the *Eobard Thawne* type but the original Wells behind the Particle Accelerator; okay, at Earth 2.

However, how did he know there is a breach that opened up at S.T.A.R. Labs? In-fact how did he catch that wormhole even at *his* Earth?

Is there any evidence at the comic or so?

I know it's too early to question this but may be I may get an answer here:)